# How to build indoor map navigation using ble

Tags: flutter, position, bluetooth-lowenergy, drawing

I am working on a graduation project to build a mobile app. In it, there is a section for admins to draw a map of the floor of the building (want to do as shown in Figure 1) and assign direction buttons and Bluetooth beacons on that map. The part for users will have the function of locating the current location based on Bluetooth signals emitted from the 3 nearest beacons, and directions from point A -> B.

If you find out, this project will be divided into many layers (layers) like
Layer 1: Create a coordinate system Oxy, each cell in the coordinates will have a unit of 10cmx10cm.

Layer 2: Is the class to draw obstacles (walls, cabinets, tables and chairs, ...). Obstacles are numbered 1, any accessible way is numbered 0.

Layer 3: Create location points to assign to each room, area, this layer is responsible for creating graphs for navigation.

Layer 4: Create beacons (Bluetooth tags) to apply a trilateration algorithm to find the current location of the phone based on the RSSI of the 3 nearest beacons around.

Can anyone tell me if this model is ok?

Does anyone have any keywords to draw maps on android?

My Bluetooth tag in use is here: [i.imgur.com/DdNPmWn.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG25r.jpg) , Does anyone think it is possible to locate using this device ?, I found it very cheap, I also see other research, they use more expensive devices like this [i.imgur.com/54KbvTZ.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrwLz.jpg) or Eddystone.

Thank you very much.

[Figure 1 ]
[image: Figure 1]

[Layer1]
[image: Layer1]

[Layer2]
[image: Layer2]

[Layer3]
[image: Layer3]

[Layer4] :
[image: Layer4]

Comment: Keep in mind that distance calculation from BLE RSSI is not very accurate. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61653469/7473793

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan thank you for giving me a useful link, I will apply KalmanFilter for the project.

Comment: My Bluetooth tag in use is here: https://i.imgur.com/DdNPmWn.jpg , do you think it is possible to locate using this device ?, I found it very cheap, I also see other research, they use more expensive devices like this https://i.imgur.com/54KbvTZ.jpg or Eddystone.

Comment: Maybe you can [edit]  your question and add the name of the tag and a link to some description to your question

Comment: Do you want to determine the position of the tag or do you want to use the tag as "beacon" to determine the position of the phone?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I want to use the tag as beacon to determine the position of the phone,  I have about 30 tags to stick to the wall every 3 meter