# Calculate the approximate distance from estimote beacon on android

Tags: android, distance, beacon

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784516/estimating-beacon-proximity-distance-based-on-rssi-bluetooth-le) but I do not know if my understanding is correct on the matter and where (if I) missing:
I use an app with two distinct lib, one with the sdk estimote and am trying to calculate the distance based on this formula and the other using the [lib Alt Beacon](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html).

Formula:

```
double getDistance(int rssi, int txPower) {
    /*
     * RSSI = TxPower - 10 * n * lg(d)
     * n = 2 (in free space)
     * 
     * d = 10 ^ ((TxPower - RSSI) / (10 * n))
     */

    return Math.pow(10d, ((double) txPower - rssi) / (10 * 2));
}
```

Alt Beacon returns me a value close to correct, but when trying to use the formula of this post according to my understanding the value of this distance very different.

My Estimote formula:

```
double getDistance(int rssi, int txPower) {
    /*
     * RSSI = TxPower - 10 * n * lg(d)
     * n = 2 (in free space)
     * 
     * d = 10 ^ ((TxPower - RSSI) / (10 * n))
     */

    return Math.pow(10d, ((double) beacon.getMeasuredPower() - beacon.getRssi()) / (10 * 2));
}
```

Sample beacon estimote values:

```
beacon.getMeasuredPower() = -65
beacon.getRssi() = -66
```

Distance value returned by Alt lib = + - 4 meters.

Distance value returned by the formula = + - 20 meters.

What are the actual amounts to be placed in the formula so that I can have the distance to the beacon, and if you can learn in a plane x, y position as a radar.

Comment: Give me a day. I ll share the code. I have developed an application to estimate the position of the user using Estimote Beacon.

But the one that I have uses the Estimote SDK

Comment: What is the question?