# Is there way to detect a certain phone from a few feet away

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, nfc, rfid, smartphone

I am trying to build a system with a raspberry pi that allows clients access into a building depending on their membership status. Right now, it uses QR codes, but I want to know if it is possible to add a feature where it uses some technology like NFC or RFID or Bluetooth to detect their phone or RFID card from at least a foot away and confirm they have a membership.

Someone told me I could use RFID, but I am only aware of that being used in short-distance applications, like a card on a hotel door. I am not sure about Bluetooth either, because the phone would have to connect to the pi first, right? Maybe there is something I don't know about. So please offer any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think bluetooth does good work for tracking user. Since it's the best to handle large distances than NFC and RFID these two technologies are used for low range scenarios, check this [link](https://www.scienceabc.com/innovation/what-is-the-range-of-bluetooth-and-how-can-it-be-extended.html).
In addition, you can check [distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784516/estimating-beacon-proximity-distance-based-on-rssi-bluetooth-le)(using Proximity and RSSI) and membership status as well. but you need to know how to handle bluetooth connectivity with raspberry pi check this [link](https://scribles.net/setting-up-bluetooth-serial-port-profile-on-raspberry-pi/). as well create an app on that mobile phone to use Bluetooth (depending which OS you're using for [Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth), [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/bluetooth/)).
Regards,