# Calculate distance using Android BLE (Bluetooth low energy)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ble-txpower

I tried to get distance between two mobile devices using BLE, I known that is a common task, and we can using `RSSI` and `txPower` to find out the distance.

But I have a problem to get `txPower` value in android BLE. It's always return 127 (TX_POWER_NOT_PRESENT), although I already add it in `AdvertiseData`

```
val data = AdvertiseData.Builder().setIncludeDeviceName(false).setIncludeTxPowerLevel(true)
            .addServiceUuid(pUuid).build()
```

Below is code block using to get `txPower`

```
private fun processScanResult(scanResult: ScanResult?) {

            var txPower: Int? = null

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                txPower = scanResult?.txPower
                if (txPower == 127) {
                    txPower = null
                }
            }
        }
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for my issue? Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Estimating beacon proximity/distance based on RSSI - Bluetooth LE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22784516/295004) and [Understanding ibeacon distancing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20416218/295004)

Comment: For someone who faces this situation, I think some device, I means the manufacturer, don't expose `txPower` in `ScanResult`.so still haven't another solution to fix this

Comment: No solutions yet?