# Does RSSI depend on beacon and device?

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, rssi

I've read in many places that RSSI is highly environment specific (e.g., [walls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22796163/564709) or [weather](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16927330/564709)) which can make it difficult to infer which beacon is the closest in a Euclidean sort of way. I also gather that [RSSI is measured in *arbitrary units* from 0 (good connection strength) to -100 (bad connection strength)](https://superuser.com/a/21847/126633). In spite of these challenges, I have questions about the following two thought experiments related to the reliability of the RSSI values for beacon <--> device communications.

**Experiment 1.** Given a particular beacon and two devices located at the exact same location, will those two devices register the same RSSI for that beacon?

**Experiment 2.** Given a particular device and two beacons located at the exact same location, will those two beacons register the same RSSI for that device?

To formalize this in a statistical sense, will p(signal | beacon1, device1) = p(signal | beacon2, device2) if beacon1-device1 are placed in the exact same environment of beacon2-device2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since different antennas and devices have different RF properties, I'm going to go ahead and say that unless your beacons/devices are identical to each other, then no, you should not expect the same RSSI reading, even if their locations are identical. This is because the device cannot know how much power is in an RF signal before it passes through its circuitry, and better and bigger antennas will transmit/receive better than crappier ones.

That said, RSSI values of 0 will be read as 0 with both devices, and also maximum RSSI values, assuming that the two devices use the same RSSI scale, which doesn't seem to have to be the case, as wikipedia says: "As an example, Cisco Systems cards have a RSSI_Max value of 100 and will report 101 different power levels, where the RSSI value is 0 to 100. Another popular Wi-Fi chipset is made by Atheros. An Atheros based card will return an RSSI value of 0 to 127 (0x7f) with 128 (0x80) indicating an invalid value."

Anyway, if your devices *are* identical, then I would expect the readings to be identical as well, or at least very close to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the differences in hardware and transmission power, timing is also important. If the interval between two measurements conducted by either the same device/beacon or different ones exceed channel coherence time, RSSI may vary drastically. Coherence time in indoor environment is at the level of 1s, and 10-100 times smaller outdoor.